# How to put multiple condition on foreach loop using php

Tags: php, if-statement, drupal

Below is my code:

```
function ublox_salesforce_salesforce_webforms_save_submission_alter(&$fields, $context) {
  foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, ["Date_Prototype__c", "Date_Production__c", "NBIOT_Date_of_Field_Trial__c", "NBIOT_Date_Lab_Trial__c"])) {
      $fields[$key] = trim($value);

      if ($key == 'Date_Production__c') {
        $production_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fields['Date_Production__c']));
        $fields[$key] = $production_date;
      }
}
```

You can see I have put condition on "Date_production__c" and it is working fine for me
now I want to apply same condition on "Date_Prototype__c" how I can do apply?

I have tried by copy paste my condition as with 'Date_Production__C"

Like below:

```
          function ublox_salesforce_salesforce_webforms_save_submission_alter(&$fields, $context) {
  foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, ["Date_Prototype__c", "Date_Production__c", "NBIOT_Date_of_Field_Trial__c", "NBIOT_Date_Lab_Trial__c"])) {
      $fields[$key] = trim($value);

      if ($key == 'Date_Production__c') {
        $production_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fields['Date_Production__c']));
        $fields[$key] = $production_date;
      }

      if ($key == 'Date_Prototype__c') {
        $prototype_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fields['Date_Prototype__c']));
        $fields[$key] = $prototype_date;
      }
}
```

But it is not working as when i print 'Date_Prototype__c' using drupal_set_message it is printing wrong date like   1970-01-01 bit it is working fine with first condition with 'Date_Production__c'

any idea? where I am doing wrong?
Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `$fields['Date_Prototype__c']`? Try to `var_dump` it and see what it contains.

Comment: I it possible $fields['Date_Prototype__c'] to be an empty string ?

Comment: @AngelDeykov no it is not possible it is required

Comment: then show us whats inside that variable, since you get 1970-01-01 out of formatting it means there is something wrong with the string you pass

Comment: make 1 var_dump($fields['Date_Prototype__c']); and see what you have inside

Comment: I have done var_dump but it is not printing anything, but when i use drupal_set_message($fields['Date_Prototype__c']);  it shows 1970-01-01

Comment: I am using drupal

Comment: Did you put that before the `if`s?

Comment: I have put both ways before and after like this:  var_dump($fields['Date_Prototype__c']);
      if ($key == 'Date_Prototype__c') {
        $prototype_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fields['Date_Prototype__c']));
        $fields[$key] = $prototype_date;
        var_dump($fields['Date_Prototype__c']);
      }

Comment: but not printing anything else

Comment: So you got the answer of your question - "I have done var_dump but it is not printing anything", that's why you get the "default" 1970-01-01, because you're trying to convert empty string ...

Comment: what should I do now? I mean is my conditon which I have shared is fine?

Comment: I meant the `drupal_set_message` call.

Comment: so what should I do now?

Comment: So far what you appear to have told us is that the value of the field is 1970-01-01, which it would stand to reason gives you the same date when you convert it. Your next step is why is it getting that value passed to the function.

Comment: $fields['Date_Prototype__c'] is empty ... Problem is not in the code, but you're passing empty string and trying to convert it to Unix timestamp, because this conversion fails, you get 1970-01-01 ...

Comment: well I have also do var_dump with production date it printed nothing as well but it shows correct date when I do drupal_set_message